# Error: DocumentSnapshot.get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transaction'

Tags: python, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I need to update the documents in collection. But I would like to run transaction for every document:

```py
async def example():
    @google.cloud.firestore.async_transactional
    async def update_in_transaction(transaction, city_ref, data):
        snapshot = await city_ref.get(
            transaction=transaction
        )  # <= Error: DocumentSnapshot.get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transaction'
        transaction.update(city_ref, data)

    # prepare data
    db: google.cloud.firestore.AsyncClient = AsyncClient()
    await db.document("1/1").set({"a": 1})
    await db.document("1/2").set({"a": 2})

    # try to update document outside of the loop
    city_ref = db.collection("1").document("1")
    transaction = db.transaction()
    await update_in_transaction(transaction, city_ref, {"a": 3})  # <= no error here

    # try to update within loop
    docs = db.collection("1").stream()
    async for doc in docs:
        transaction = db.transaction()
        await update_in_transaction(transaction, doc, {"a": 3})  # <= error here


asyncio.run(example())
```

I am getting a strange error `DocumentSnapshot.get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'transaction'` when trying to do it. Why is that?

Comment: Are you facing same error with [`@firestore.async_transactional`](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/samples/firestore-transaction-document-update-async#code-sample) library as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `city_ref` is a `DocumentReference`, then I don't think you can pass a transaction to its [`get()` method](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/firestore/latest/document#getfieldpath-strhttpspythonreadthedocsioenlatestlibrarystdtypeshtmlstr).

Instead you should construct a transaction, and [call `get()`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/firestore/latest/transaction#getreforquery-retry-googleapicoreretryretry--methoddefaultdefaultvalue-object-object-timeout-optionalfloat--none) with the document reference on that.

Let me know if that works, because if so, we'll probably have to update the [code sample in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#python).

Comment: As far as I see - `cityRef` is `DocumentReference` (and it works with its `get()`), but `doc` is `DocumentSnapshot` and it doesn't work with its `get()`. But your approach works for the last, thanks